# Request for comment thread cleanup

Tags: discussion

can I request a comment thread cleanup / move to chat on this answer, since the comment trail has gotten a bit acerbic, is too long, and has drifted far out of scope for the answer:

https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/79574/62445

thanks!

Comment: Stuff like this is often more suited to a general flag on the question itself, rather than a meta post. Flag as 'other' and request a comment cleanup.

Comment: thanks....good tip!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because one should flag the post instead of posting on meta. No offence :-)

Comment: None taken... I'm voting to delete it! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve granted and executed your request :-)